# MySQL CASE statement syntax with * operator explaination

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a CASE statement that looks like the following

```
        case
            when ph.term_start_date > x.year1 then 0
            DATEDIFF(case when ph.term_end_date > x.year1 then x.year1 else ph.term_end_date end, greatest(x.report_date, ph.term_start_date))
        end days_remaining_year1,
        case
            when ph.term_start_date > x.year1 then 0
            DATEDIFF(case when ph.term_end_date > x.year1 then x.year1 else ph.term_end_date end, greatest(x.report_date, ph.term_start_date))
        end *(ph.amount + ifnull(y.credit,0))/DATEDIFF(ph.term_end_date, ph.term_start_date) as deferral_year1,
```

I need to understand what the `*` after the `END` keyword on the last line means. I thought after the end keyword you had to specifiy a column that will appear in the result set

```
Case 
When ( something )
end ( return column )
```

Answer (score 2):

`*` is the **multiplication** operator

Doc : [MySQL Arithmetic Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html)

---

The preceding `CASE` is returning a value and you multiply it by :

```
(ph.amount + ifnull(y.credit,0))/DATEDIFF(ph.term_end_date, ph.term_start_date)
```

the result of this is returned in the column `deferral_year1`

---

***Edit***: answer to comment

I sneaked closely on your 2 `CASE` statements and they look incorrect to me. Does your query execute without error ?

It looks like there's a missing `else` before the DATEDIFF, it should be this IMO

```
    case
        when ph.term_start_date > x.year1 then 0
        else DATEDIFF(case when ph.term_end_date > x.year1 then x.year1 else ph.term_end_date end, greatest(x.report_date, ph.term_start_date))
    end
```

So like you said if `ph.term_start_date > x.year1` it should returns 0, **else** it returns the result of the `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: So in the second CASE statement, it checks the WHEN clause to either return 0 or the result of the DATEDIFF?